# Jenkins and Kubernetes CLI plugin and GKE

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use Jenkins Kubernetes CLI plugin from https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/ to let deploy artifacts from Jenkins to GKE cluster.

### Expected Behavior

Get cluster info on `kubectl cluster-info`

### Actual Behavior

Error out as `Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

Output of generated `./kube/config`

```
+ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy
  name: my-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: my-cluster
    user: jenkins-pipeline
  name: my-cluster-jenkins
current-context: my-cluster-jenkins
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: jenkins-pipeline
  user:
    username: jenkins-pipelin
```

When I run from a command line I need to do

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/key.json`

Where that part goes in that plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the sh?

```
withKubeConfig(...) {
  sh “””
    export ...
    kubectl ...
  “””
}
```

Comment: That will not work as by default plugin is working with user access with token not the `key.json`

Comment: So when you run from command line with the `export`, subsequent `kubectl` (per plugin page) reads the contents of the file?

Comment: From the plugin page, you want to somehow use the contents of your `key.json` file for `credentialsId`?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever machine you're running `kubectl` on is reading a kube config (likely `~/.kube/config`) with a `client-certificate-data` or `client-key-data` that doesn't correspond to the server you're communicating with.

You likely want to remove `~/.kube/config` and use the one you download from Google.